# Which Evolutionary Algorithm for optimization of binary problems?

Tags: c++, windows, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

In our program we use a genetic algorithm since years to sole problems for n variables, each having a fixed set of m possible values. This typically works well for ~1,000 variables and 10 possibilities.

Now i have a new task where only two possibilities (on/off) exist for each variable, but i'll probably need to solve systems with 10,000 or more variables. The existing GA does work but the solution improves only very slowly.

All the EA i find are designed rather for continuous or integer/float problems. Which one is best suited for binary problems?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed description of the problem to be solved?

Comment: You can think of it as a number of 'switches' in electronic circuits that are needed to fulfill some safety criteria. We define the circuits layout and a number of potential switch positions. Then we want to minimize the number of switches needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like DonAndre said, canonical GA was pretty much designed for binary problems.

However...

**No evolutionary algorithm is in itself a magic bullet** (unless it has billions of years runtime).  What matters most is your representation, and how that interacts with your mutation and crossover operators: together, these define the 'intelligence' of what is essentially a heuristic search in disguise.  The aim is for each operator to have a fair chance of producing offspring with similar fitness to the parents, so if you have domain-specific knowledge that allows you to do better than randomly flipping bits or splicing bitstrings, then use this.

Roulette and tournament selection and elitism are good ideas (maybe preserving more than 1, it's a black art, who can say...).  You may also benefit from adaptive mutation.  The old rule of thumb is that 1/5 of offspring should be better than the parents - keep track of this quantity and vary the mutation rate appropriately.  If offspring are coming out worse then mutate less; if offspring are consistently better then mutate more.  But the mutation rate needs an inertia component so it doesn't adapt too rapidly, and as with any metaparameter, setting this is something of a black art.  Good luck!

Comment: The 1/5th success rule was invented for evolution strategies by Rechenberg. It was calculated by analyzing a certain mathematical function and shown that the expected value of improving children is about 1/5 the number of parents over the whole search space. More modern adaptive mutation schemes are sigma-self-adaption and covariance-matrix-adaption, however again developed mainly for real-valued optimization with the evolution strategy.

For GAs the mutation is usually seen as an unbiased random perturbation that readds some diversity to an otherwise quickly converging evolutionary search.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the Genetic Algorithm in its canonical form is among the best suited metaheuristics for binary decision problems. The default configuration that I would try is such a genetic algorithm that uses 1-elitism and that is configured with roulette-wheel selection, single point crossover (100% crossover rate) and bit flip mutation (e.g. 5% mutation probability). I would suggest you try this combination with a modest population size (100-200). If this does not work well, I would suggest to increase the population size, but also change the selection scheme to a tournament selection scheme (start with binary tournament selction and increase the tournament group size if you need even more selection pressure). The reason is that with a higher population size, the fitness-proportional selection scheme might not excert the necessary amount of selection pressure to drive the search towards the optimal region.

As an alternative, we have developed an advanced version of the GA and termed it [Offspring Selection Genetic Algorithm](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.70.2448%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=5rmvToa7JITLswbFn5By&usg=AFQjCNEHYkYtFHe3NMwJBCdMRLidfFdj6w). You can also consider trying to solve this problem with a trajectory-based algorithm like Tabu Search or Simulated Annealing that just uses mutation to move from one solution to another by just making small changes.

We have a GUI-driven software ([HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com)) that allows you to experiment with a number of metaheuristics on several problems. Your problem is unfortunately not included, but it's GPL licensed and you can implement your own problem there (through just the GUI even, there's a howto for that).

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a linear/integer program?

Comment: If i only have 32 Switches this sums up to 4.294.967.295 possibilities. If we assume that a machine evaluates 100 combinations / second the total run time would be 42.949.672 seconds which is more than 497 days of runtime. If you would like to try all combinations of 10.000 switches, i guess its even hard to write a integer number for the total number of possibilities: Its 2**10000.

Comment: Integer programming is not a brute-force search. It takes into account the constraints of your problem to find things quickly - and it always finds the global minimum. Unfortunately not all problems can be solved efficiently, however, a surprising number can. It might be worth trying to reformulate your problem as such.